# Input size attribute vs div width attribute

Tags: html, css

In my html page I have an input component placed above a div component.
I want the input and the div to have the same width, the input has a "size" attribtue of 30.
If I use the "style" attribute of the div with "width : 30ch" or with "width : 30em" it doesn't seem to work, the div component is getting way wider than the input component in both cases.

Which attribute should I use to make the div's width match the input's size attribute?

code :

```
<input type="text" readonly="yes" value="a" size="30" ID="b">
<div id="c" style="width : 30ch"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `size` attribute sets the visible width in “characters”, and browsers interpret this differently. The `ch` unit, in supporting browsers, means the width of the digit `0`, so it is defined very exactly, though it of course depends on the font. So these two ways of setting width are incommensurable.

To make a `div` element after an `input` element exactly as wide as the `input` element, the simplest way is to wrap them in a table with fixed layout. (Those who can’t bear with HTML tables can use a CSS table instead.) You don’t set the width of the `div` element at all in this approach; it gets its width from the table formatting. I have just set some content and a background color for it so that the width of the element is visible.

```html
<table style="table-layout: fixed" cellspacing=0>
<tr><td><input type="text" readonly="yes" value="a" size="30" ID="b">
<tr><td><div id="c" style="background: green">Hello world</div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try width attribute in both i.e. in input and div also , plus try to give width in %

html:

```
  <html>
  <input id="myinput"></input>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </html>
```

css :

```
 #myDiv{
     width:x%(set x per your requirement)
 }
```

Comment: I would rather do it without changing the input component, and just changing the div, is it possible?

Comment: i have removed the input css and made changes above please try that and let me know  whether its working for you or not

Comment: Would it be helpful? If input's size attribute is 30, then what should be the div's width? 30%?

Comment: no you need to set both attribute in same parameter either both are in % or both in px, ofcourse you can set one in px and one in % but that would be bad practice to follow

Answer (score 0):

Use this style to set exact same width for both your input and your div

```
input#b, div#c {width:100px;}
```